# angular: slow startup after upgrading to rc6

Tags: angular

Since the github-issue-tracker seems to be the wrong place to discuss this problem, I turn to SO:

After upgrading from angular rc5 to rc6 the startup-time of my application went from 1 second to 30 seconds.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11334

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11371

Obviously my question would be: What am I doing wrong?

PS: Template-Parse-Errors are thrown on startup even in templates that are not used by the entry-component. This behaviour seems new to me in rc6...

another-PS: We are using a lot of "styleUrls" in our components. Might this be the source of the issue as indicated in a comment in the second github-link?

Comment: Did you switch to ngModules or no?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem was solved**:

In rc6 a regular expression triggered so called "back-tracking" and thereby caused high cpu-load. In the nightly-builds of angular this problem is fixed and performance is restored.